# AWS Cloudwatch Alarm Terraform configuration

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have configured following AWS Cloudwatch alarm using terraform. However when I look at the alarm data, I don't see any values. Alarm does not trigger.

```
resource "aws_cloudwatch_metric_alarm" "Test_Alarm" {
  alarm_name          = "Test_Alarm"
  comparison_operator = "GreaterThanOrEqualToThreshold"
  evaluation_periods  = "1"
  metric_name         = "RequestCount"
  namespace           = "AWS/ApplicationELB"
  period              = "60"
  statistic           = "Sum"
  threshold           = "2"
  alarm_description   = "Test_Alarm_ALB"
  treat_missing_data  = "notBreaching"
  alarm_actions       = ["${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}"]
  ok_actions          = ["${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}"]
  dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = aws_alb.application_load_balancer.name
  }
}

# SNS Topic for Errors
resource "aws_sns_topic" "sns_topic" {
  name = "${var.app_name}-sns_topic"
}

resource "aws_sns_topic_policy" "notify_policy" {
  arn    = aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn
  policy = data.aws_iam_policy_document.notify_policy.json
}

data "aws_iam_policy_document" "notify_policy" {
  statement {
    actions = [
      "SNS:Publish",
    ]

    resources = [
      "${aws_sns_topic.sns_topic.arn}",
    ]

    principals {
      type        = "Service"
      identifiers = ["cloudwatch.amazonaws.com"]
    }
  }
}
```

[Cloudwatch alarm metric - Test_Alarm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCLN9.png)

Comment: Can you provide any explanation on what this alarm is supposed to do exactly? When it should be triggered?

Comment: Alarm should trigger when request count for ALB is greater than 2. Description of Request Count metric as per AWS "The number of requests processed over IPv4 and IPv6. This metric is only incremented for requests where the load balancer node was able to choose a target. Requests rejected before a target is chosen (for example, HTTP 460, HTTP 400, some kinds of HTTP 503 and 500) are not reflected in this metric."

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Solved this query. Had issue in "dimensions".

instead of Load balancer value of .name

```
dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = aws_alb.application_load_balancer.name
  }
```

should have used .arn_suffix

```
dimensions = {
    LoadBalancer = aws_alb.application_load_balancer.arn_suffix
  }
```